# Fix a Truecrypt Volume

Tags: truecrypt, encrypting-file-system, disk-encryption

I've have a backup volume using truecrypt (USB Disk, entire disk (eg /dev/sdb)) accidentally added to a Windows System and then using windows that disk has been initialized.

No other action has been taken on that disk.

The disk no longer mounts.

Assuming no other external sources (backups of the headers etc) is it possible to fix that volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that without a backup this is impossible by design.

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Recover_a_TrueCrypt_Volume